# Create a new line for my last column using awk

Tags: unix, awk, newline

I have the file:

```
A cars1 black NY
A cars2       W
A cars3 black SP
```

I would like to transform the last column into a new line and add the `>` symbol:

```
A cars1 black
>NY
A cars2       
>W
A cars3 black 
>SP
```

I tried the command below, but it did not work very well, maybe because of the missing values of the third column:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,"\n"$4}'
```

Comment: I did an improvement in my command and also worked: awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"}; BEGIN{OFS="\t"};{print $1,$2,$3,"\n"">"$4}'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In sed:

```
$ sed 's/[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\)$/\n>\1/' infile
A cars1 black
>NY
A cars2
>W
A cars3 black
>SP
```

This takes the last sequence of blanks followed by non-blanks and substitutes them by a newline, `>` and the captured non-blanks.

Notice that some seds complain about inserting a newline like this. Alternatives are:

- Insert a literal newline

  ```
  sed 's/[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\)$/\
  >\1/' infile
  ```
- Insert an ANSI-escaped newline

  ```
  sed 's/[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\)$/'$'\n''>\1/' infile
  ```
- Command substitution

  ```
  sed 's/[[:blank:]]*\([^[:blank:]]*\)$/'"$(printf '\n')"'>\1/' infile
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '{$NF=ORS ">" $NF; print}' file
```

The point is to modify the last field `$NF` and then just print the whole record `$0`.

Comment: Something to note (though maybe the OP doesn't care) is that this will leave the trailing field separator on the odd-numbered lines

Comment: @EdMorton Well this time I always set there something non-null.

Comment: Btw @TomFenech,  @EdMorton is there a short way of doing that and to lose that trailing `OFS` while at it? Nothing short pops to my mind atm.

Comment: With GNU awk: `'{$0=gensub(/\s+(\S+)$/,"\n>\\1",1)}1'`

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah, that crossed my mind but I'm trying to quit using it. :D

Comment: GNU awk has too many goodies to quit using it. We just need the rest of the world to always use it :-).

Comment: @EdMorton No I meant `gensub` specifically. <3 GNU awk. Well, I'll let that rub in for awhile.

Comment: Why avoid gensub()? It's not even entirely gawk-specific now as mawk also supports it. With other awks btw it'd be `'{x=$NF; sub(/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/,""); print $0 "\n>" x}'`.

Comment: @Ed bug/feature would be that both of those don't work with trailing spaces in the input.

Comment: @TomFenech You can always add `\s*` (gawk) or `[[:space:]]*` before the `$` if that's a concern.

Answer (score 1):

In awk you can do it 'mechanically':

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) printf "%s%s",$i,i==NF-1 ? ORS : OFS; print ">" $NF}' file
A cars1 black
>NY
A cars2
>W
A cars3 black
>SP
```